# XSL Modify element value from another element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to be able modify value of element A from template of element B

**XML input**

```
<Parent>
   <Elem1 Attr="Something" OtherAttr="Other">ExistingValue</Elem1>
   <Elem2 Attr="SomethingElse" />
</Parent>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Elem1">
   <!-- SOMEHOW MODIFY HERE VALUE OF ELEM2 -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected XML output**

```
<Parent>
 <Elem1 Attr="Something" OtherAttr="Other">ExistingValue</Elem1>
 <Elem2 Attr="SomethingElse">Value from elem1</Elem2>
</Parent>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you expect to do. If you have a template matching `Elem1` and want to process the `Elem2` sibling then you can of course do that by selecting e.g. `following-sibling::Elem2`. Not sure what you expect to do with the element, unless you want to break the established processing and process it with `xsl:for-each` or (XSLT 3) `xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Elem2"`.

Comment: The example you have given does not show any value taken from the `Elem1` data and you have not blocked the identity based processing of `Elem2` so I am not sure where and why you want to break the normal processing.

Comment: do not rely that elem1 and elem 2 are siblings, they can be anywhere in xml. My point is to be able modify value of element 2 based on attirbute of element 1, but it has to be provided in elem1 template match. Is it more clear now?

Comment: The usual way would be to write an `xsl:template match="Elem2"` that would then select/pull any values from e.g. `//Elem1` or `//Elem1/@foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea.

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Elem1">
  <!-- Write out Elem1. -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Elem2" mode="outElem2">
    <xsl:with-param name="Elem1Attr" select="@Attr"/>
    <!-- You could also pass the value from Elem1 here. -->
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Suppress Elem2-->
<xsl:template match="Elem2"/>

<!--**** outElem2 mode. -->  
<xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="outElem2">
  <xsl:param name="Elem1Attr"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="outElem2">
      <xsl:with-param name="Elem1Attr" select="@Attr"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Elem2" mode="outElem2">
  <xsl:param name="Elem1Attr"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- Output the attributes. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="outElem2"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$Elem1Attr = 'Something'">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Value from elem1'"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'Something else'"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Cool.  Can you check the up arrow next to my answer to close out this question and give me the points?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "modify" things in XSLT. Your stylesheet takes an XML document as input and produces another XML document as output. It's best to think of your stylesheet as writing the output sequentially, accessing whatever part of the input it needs to construct each result element as it is generated. The only time you can set the value of element E is when you are writing element E. (That's an excessively time-oriented picture of what's going on, but it's a useful mental model.)

In your example, the code for setting the value of Elem2 would normally belong in the template rule for Elem2.